# Query to find the percentage difference of each row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some columns in it. I would like to write a query that iterates through each row and find the total count of all rows that match a column in the selected row and also find the count of all rows that match 2 columns. With these 2 values, I would like to find the percentage difference and print them as column1, percentage(query1(column2)/query2(column2 and column3)).

Below is the query which I wrote

```
    SELECT DISTINCT (t2.column1)
    ,(
        SELECT count(DISTINCT column2)
        FROM table1 t1
        WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1
        ORDER BY column2
        ) AS total_count
    ,(
        SELECT count(DISTINCT column2)
        FROM table1 t1
        WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1
            AND column3 IN (
                10
                ,20
                )
        ORDER BY column1
            ,column2
            ,column3
        ) AS column3_count
FROM table1 t2;
```

The above query works but takes a lot of time to process.

I want it as

```
   SELECT DISTINCT (column1)
    ,percentage(query1 that matches ALL rows WITH column1 / query2 that match ALL rows WITH column1
        AND SOME other CONSTRAINT)
FROM TABLE t1
```

I would like to optimize the above query too. Please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  For the counts:

```
select t1.column1,
       count(distinct column2) as num_column2,
       count(distinct case when column3 in (10, 20) then column2 end) as num_column2_column3
from table1 t1
group by t1.column1;
```

I don't understand the calculation for the percentage, but it would seem to be based on these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.column1,
       count(distinct column2) as num_column2,
       count(distinct case when column3 in (10, 20) then column2 end) as num_column2_column3
from table1 t1
group by t1.column1;
```